# Make Visual Studio Debugger Target Correct Application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, vsto, excel-addins

My workplace is making the jump from Office 2010 to 2013. There are a few VSTO Add-Ins that were built in-house. I am working on testing them. On my dev machine I have 2010 and 2013 installed so that I can test things, but also still support 2010 stuff.

I also have Visual Studio 2010. When I run the debugger, it launches Office 2010. I have been trying to figure out where the target application is set in a VSTO Add-In. 2013 is set as the default application for the machine in general, and the Add-Ins load in 2013 when I install it. I just need the debugger to launch 2013 when I run it.

If I really need to, I can uninstall 2010 and keep another machine around for that purpose, but this seems like there has to be a small setting I'm missing. I have definitely googled around, though. The best thing I found was this: http://www.greycastle.se/vsto-project-office-target-version/ but a) he doesn't say WHERE this is, and b) it's from 3 years ago, I don't know if I would get a response if I asked.

Any ideas? Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the VSTO project -> Properties -> Debug. Under "Start external program" select the executable you wish to run.

When I test different versions I just replace the "Office14" with the "Office15" since all the other paths remain the same (this switches from Office 2010 to Office 2013).